# Is there a more efficient way of querying HTML data than in an SQlite database?

Tags: database, django, sqlite, database-design, document-oriented-db

Maybe my question will be closed because it is not "constructive" enough but anyway... I've already searched for answers but most of them are too general. For my master thesis project I have to crawl lots of (i.e. several thousands) webpages and entirely store them in a database. This is necessary because I have to analyze them in different ways, try out several machine learning algorithms and parse them in different ways. At the moment, I'm using an SQlite database for this purpose, in combination with Django as the preferred web framework.

I've put the entire HTML data of a single webpage into a Django `TextField`, i.e. for each webpage there is a separate row in the database table and all the webpage's content is stored in a single column of the table. The problem now is that querying and sorting the data and especially iterating over it is very slow. I've crawled around 1000 webpages so far and the database file already is over 2 GB in size. Furthermore, my 4 GB of RAM are filled entirely and my computer (Macbook Pro mid-2009, Core2Duo 2.26 Ghz, 500 GB HDD, OSX 10.8) becomes unresponsive. If I restrict the number of items to be pre-cached, then processing the data becomes even slower because the number of queries increases. Since I have to crawl even more data, my current setup doesn't scale well enough.

**My question now is the following:**
How can I store my HTML data more efficiently such that querying the data can be done faster? Does it make sense to switch to another RDBMS such as MySQL or PostgreSQL? Or would you recommend a document-oriented database system such as MongoDB? I only have experience with SQlite so far, so I have no idea really what to use. As the deadline for my master thesis is coming nearer, I don't have the time to try out lots of different setups.

In order to help you in helping me, here are some further requirements:

- more performance in querying large HTML data compared to SQlite while not eating up all memory of my computer (workload cannot be distributed to other computers)
- more or less good integration with Django
- this is research work only so it will never run in a production environment but only on my computer (maybe also on my Professor's one)

It would be great if you helped me in deciding which direction I should take because I feel somehow lost with this huge amount of possibilities. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: What data are you querying in the html page?  Are you performing some basic text searching?

Comment: @Jeremy Text searching is one part, yes, but I also have to analyze the HTML structure of the webpages and use it as training data for several machine learning algorithms.That's why I have to store the webpages in their entirety and not only the textual content.

Comment: Many databases (MySQL, SQLAnywhere, MS-SQL Server, etc) provide built-in functions to help with parsing XML data, which could be of some use (provided the HTML is well formed...).  This would theoretically bring down your query time, depending on what you're after...

Comment: Another thought would be separate the webpage based on "typical" components, and stored them separately (ie, store the "head" and "body" nodes separately).  This would improve query time when looking for things in one or the other, if that's necessary.

Comment: @sybkar Separating the webpage into several components sounds like a good idea for a start. Thanks for the idea. For parsing, I have used _lxml_ so far which works pretty fine.

Comment: @PeterStahl _lxml_ looks like it would work just fine, but the idea of using a database which supports XML natively is that it will not only reduce the time spent performing the query, but also the time transporting the results between the database and your program (which, depending on the size of your result set, could be quite significant).  What type of operations are you doing on the database now? SELECT-WHERE-LIKE? REGEXP?

Comment: @sybkar So far I have only used Django's ORM to query databases, so I don't know which SQL operations are performed internally. I mainly use Django's queryset methods [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get) and [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and then analyze the data using XPath expressions provided by _lxml_.

Answer (score 2):

This is merely an answer but suggestions you should consider. Your problem is far to specific to taken care of with a code-snippet or a hint.

**First**: try to reduce fetched data as much as possible.
This said, why store the complete HTML code, I guess you are only interested in the text published on the webpage (aka content). So strip the data during the crawl from the HTML stuff and store the pure information.
If I am wrong and you are interested in something else, feel free to correct me.

**Second**: try to produce queryable data. Your crawler should write the data in the database in a fashion you can process data easier. A map-reduce approach could be the way to go. This will take more time crawling but enables fast data retrival afterwards.
This is pretty much storing only a map to all the pages you crawled and not the complete content any more or at least, your query wont touch the full data tables and only rely on the mapreduced content first.

**Third**: upgrade your hardware - you want to process alot of data? Be prepared (or bring time with you). Stick in as much RAM as you want and can to your Macbook (you can put ram inside right?! please say you can upgrade ram in apple stuff..) since it is really cheap

**Fourth**: SQLite is hdd-heavy since it relies on the OS io-cache and so on and sometimes needs ages to refetch data.
If you can try to get it on an SSD drive (which will be unhealthy for the SSD in the long run ;-) ) or use a remote database with a fast connection to your pc so the hdd->ram->cpu cycle is not your limitation but only RAM and maybe CPU (I guess your program is not multi-core right?)

**Fifths and final:** even though I hate throwing in fancy words that are in the media everywhere now, have a look at IBMs article about [hadoop](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-15/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. :) Regarding your first point, I also have to analyze the HTML structure of the webpages, not only the textual content. That's why I have to store the pages in their entirety. If I only needed the text, I would strip off the HTML stuff for sure. Regarding your third and fourth point: I don't have money to buy an SSD or upgrade my RAM at the moment. And no, my program is not based on multi-core functionality. It's a web application (a search engine in particular).